# Ставится ли тире в предложении "<Имя> — один из них"?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Я только что начал писать сочинение, в котором у меня есть два следующих предложения:

> Некультурные и грубые люди всегда будут производить на других плохое
> впечатление. Сёмка Царев — один из них.

Должно ли стоять тире после "Семка Царев" или нет? Если да, то по какому правилу?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Поставил :)

Comment: Спасибо! Задавайте и дальше интересные вопросы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Сёмка Царев — один из них.***

[**Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым**](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_172) (Грамота.ру)

> Существует несколько случаев, когда для интонационно-логического членения фразы между подлежащим и сказуемым необходимо поставить тире.
>
> <...> если подлежащее и сказуемое выражены <...> существительным и словосочетанием с числительным, например: *Площадь треугольника – пять квадратных сантиметров.*

Примеры из Национального корпуса русского языка:

*Один из них ― Володя Митрофанов.* [Сергей Довлатов. Заповедник (1983)]

*Обновлённый Land Rover Discovery ― один из них.* [Хасан Ганиев. Новости // «Автопилот», 2002.09.15]